# Save product observer - detect availability

Tags: product, event-observer, stock, status

I have catalog_product_save_after observer where I want detect when product became available for sale (Magento 2.2). I'm trying to compare some attributes using this code

```
$old = $product->getOrigData('status');
$new = $product->getData('status');
```

Which attribute should I use? I was trying

- **is_in_stock** -> this is always empty
- **quantity_and_stock_status** -> old value is an array new is integer always with value 1
- **status** seems to work, but only after second product save. When I click save product once, new status value is always equal old value. When I click save second time (without changing anything) then status has new value.

How can I check this, maybe this is something connected with stockitem?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution. There is event cataloginventory_stock_item_save_after which should be used to check stock change.